# Checking for an positive integer on a form field using jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, integer

First off please see my example in JSfidle:
http://jsfiddle.net/WMxKk/1/

You can see when you click submit it prevents you if the fields haven't been filled out. But I also want to check if certain fields are an integer?

The current code I am using to check doesn't seem to work:

```
else if (required[i] == "vidHeight" && intRegex.test(input.val())) {
            // Check certain fields are positive intergers
            input.addClass("needsfilled");
            $('#' + required[i]).after('<p style="font-weight:bold;" id="' + required[i] + '_error">' + interror + '</p>');
            errornotice.fadeIn(750);
```

The if statement on it's own:

```
required[i] == "vidHeight" && intRegex.test(input.val())
```

Whats the best way to go ab out this?

Comment: Consider using [this widely known plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) instead. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Thats alot of code to add, I need this to be as light as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to negate the regex? If it's the attribute you're looking for && it's not a number, then show the error.

```
required[i] == "vidHeight" && !intRegex.test(input.val())
```

Comment: That was quick! Thanks my mistake!